# Form element in the vueJS

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I used to use PHP before and I get why forms are so common because it could literally make you submit a page and request a page from the server through a method that **you** would choose ( POST / GET ... ) . But when I made a transition to vue. I felt like using them wasn't the same since I already have Axios to get all the values from my APIs and I'm using an SPA so I wouldn't call an entire page from a server like PHP but just grab the components I need and modify the page according to my needs ( the page is dynamic ) I didn't get why I would use form since the action and method attributes aren't as useful as they used to be in PHP and I could just do all I need on a button with a type of button and get my info to the other components. And even if we were talking about a non-SPA app, it would use this.$router.push to get to the next page and you can even pass in the values in the link on a button click with a type of button and not type submit.
So my question to wrap it all up is how are forms used in Vue. Is it a common practice to use them ? The only thing I know is that it gives semantics.

Comment: Using forms has a lot of other benefits beside the submit/action handler. You can use it to bundle your data, validate data, structure your page and so on.. So yes, it is still a common practice to use them.

Comment: But I could do that validation from the backend ? A person that is smart enough could just go to that "required" attribute with Ctrl + shift + I and remove it and yea it just explodes . Maybe its just a light-weight verification but except that, that is not that big of a deal I guess .

Comment: You are right. You should never rely on front end validation for security. Validation on the front end is just to improve user experience so they don't submit something that would be rejected anyway.